# Accessing nodes returns null in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a list of searched users returned from server and add when clicked on any of the list items, get the value of inside the node component.

First I fetch the users

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (searchText.length === 0) {
            setSearchedUsers([])
            return
        }
        fetch(--users--)
        }).then((res) => res.json())
          .then((users) => {
                setSearchedUsers(users)
          })
    }, [searchText])
```

then render

```
const searchedNodes = useRef([])

function renderWithRefs() {
        return (searchedUsers.map((user, i) => (
            <div className={`searched-user-div ${i}`} ref={(div) => searchedNodes.current[i] = div} key={i} onClick={(e) => showUserData(e)}>   
                <p className="searchedUser-Name">{user.Name}</p>
                <p className="searchedUser-age">{user.Age}</p>
            </div>
        )))
    }

function showUserData(e) {
        let ref = searchedNodes.current[parseInt(e.target.className.split(" ")[1])]
        let Name = ref.querySelector(".searchedUser-Name").textContent
        let age = ref.querySelector(".searchedUser-age").textContent.slice(1)
        ....
    }
```

when clicked I get Error: cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly querying the dom in React is a very bad pattern. You should not do it unless you have no choice ( for example you need to query the size of an item ).

In your case, you could do something way easier like this:

```
<div className={`searched-user-div ${i}`} key={i} onClick={(e) => showUserData(user)}> 
     <p className="searchedUser-Name">{user.Name}</p>
     <p className="searchedUser-age">{user.Age}</p>
</div>
```

You then don't have to query the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

First,

The use of array index as a key is [not recommended](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md)

> It's a bad idea to use the array index since it doesn't uniquely
> identify your elements. In cases where the array is sorted or an
> element is added to the beginning of the array, the index will be
> changed even though the element representing that index may be the
> same. This results in unnecessary renders.

```
function renderWithRefs() {
        return (searchedUsers.map((user, i) => (
            <div className={`searched-user-div`} ref={(div) => searchedNodes.current[i] = div} key={JSON.Stringlify(user)} onClick={() => showUserData(user)} onKeyPress={() => showUserData(user)} tabIndex={0} role="button">   
                <p className="searchedUser-Name">{user.Name}</p>
                <p className="searchedUser-age">{user.Age}</p>
            </div>
        )))
    }

function showUserData(user) {
        //here you can show all user data
       <>
         <p className="searchedUser-Name">{user.Name}</p>
         <p className="searchedUser-age">{user.Age}</p>
         <p className="searchedUser-LastName">{user.LastName}</p>
         <p className="searchedUser-tel">{user.tel}</p>
         ....
       </>
        ....
    }
```

You can see I added a few props to your div all because of [no-static-element-interactions](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/no-static-element-interactions.md#no-static-element-interactions)

> Static HTML elements do not have semantic meaning. This is clear in
> the case of  and . It is less so clear in the case of
> elements that seem semantic, but that do not have a semantic mapping
> in the accessibility layer. For example , , ,
>
> , ,  and  -- to name a few -- have no
> semantic layer mapping. They are as void of meaning as .